# Best way to remove these chars from javascript string

Tags: regex, replace

I'm looking for a way to remove these characters from a string in javascript (and spaces).

```
?[]/\=<>:;,'\"&$#*()|~`!{}
```

I am unsure how to construct this:

```
"mystring is - ?[] hello ".replace(regex, "");
```

Some elements need escaping, some do not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a character class `[]`, most don't need escaping:

```
var pattern = /[?\[\]/\\=<>:;,'"&$#*()|~`!{}]/g;
"mystring is - ?[] hello ".replace(pattern, "");
```

The `g` flag is added for global replacement.

```
alert("mystring is -<> ;:,'\"&%^=!{} ?[] hello ".replace(pattern, ""));

// Prints:
mystring is - %^ hello
```

[Here it is in action](http://jsfiddle.net/9AFz9/)